# Sorting an array with c++

Tags: arrays

So I'm trying to sort an array of 10 elements provided by the user. For Example:

Person 1: 5

Person 2: 3

Person 3: 9

etc etc...

I want it to also pair the value with the person. So it should read:

person 3: 9

Person 1: 5

Person 2: 3

Sort the values in descending order.

I can sort the array, but I cant get the Person number to pair with the value....

I apologize for the lack of code, it is at home and I am at work :/

Answer (score 0):

i would suggest that you use `Map` in `c++`

```
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/
http://kengine.sourceforge.net/tutorial/g/stdmap-eng.htm
http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/CppStlMultiMap.html
```

beacuse as you can see it can hold together `string` and `int`.
and the last part is to sort it according to `int`.

Answer (score 0):

You can store each element in an `std::pair` object and use `std::algorithm` sort. Parametrizing the template with a concrete comparator which should describe your order criteria making it sort by the pair first element or the second.

You have an example at http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/sort/ which can be adapted to your needs:

```
struct myclass {
    bool operator() (pair i,pair j) { return (i.first>j.first);}
} myobject;

...
...
...

vector<pair<string, int> > vectorA = ...
sort (vectorA.begin(), vectorA.end(), myobject);
```